# What's wrong with my answer?

Tags: discussion

[My answer here](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/56584/can-body-only-dslr-capture-images/56586#56586) has just as many up votes as down votes:

[image]

Why the backlash? How can I improve my answer to appease the PSE community?

It seems to have answered their question, yet another answer has more than 5 times as many.

I agree it's not the right type of camera, I agree it's absurd. Why isn't the community asking to close it rather than upvoting an answer that says "I don't think you should get this camera"?

Answer (score 3):

I think it's probably because your first claim is demonstrably not true — you say "but it will most likely be shades of black/grey/white", but see for example https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/20974/1943.

You edited that from "only" to "most likely", but that's still not the case.

The question has a number of comments, and it seems likely that some of the downvotes many also come from earlier versions of the answer and just haven;t been removed.

Comment: But, it could be all black or all white? Hence why I said depending on the available light and shutter speed. But yes, I can see how "most likely be shades of..." can be read as a perfect portrait photo but in black and white. It also could be shades of red/blue, depending on the colour temperature.

Comment: @BBking It *could* be, but it isn't "most likely". I think the downvotes are a combination of that plus the edit seeming to be a little petulant in response to good feedback — "Okay, I'll modify my answer a little bit, but I still don't agree, so I'll leave it basically the same, I'm going to leave the original wording there but struck out, to show everyone the original thing I really wanted to say." You're free to do that, but if people disagree, it's going to get downvotes.

Answer (score 3):

A body by itself cannot capture an image in any sense that's relevant to the OP's question, i.e. *Does a “body-only” DSLR need a lens added before use?* Quibbling about whether you can cast a shadow or use a pinhole to kinda sorta make an image is misleading at best. Phillip Kendall's answer has many more up votes than yours because it's a far better answer: *You need a lens.*

Comment: I also strongly suggested to use a lens. I don't understand? Are you/others not reading my answer and just looking straight at the picture I posted and thinking "But that's not how you use a camera!"??

Comment: Even your "strong" suggestion is misleading. You make it sound like one can get along without a lens, as though a lens is a recommended option. Nobody who's asking whether or not they need a lens is operating at a level where they're considering trying their hand at pinhole photography. Your answer may be technically correct, but considering the audience it's misleading to the point of being wrong, and it's certainly not a good answer.

Comment: *but considering the audience it's misleading to the point of being wrong*. Fair enough. *certainly not a good answer.* Not so fair enough.

Comment: @BBking I'm hard pressed to think of any way that an answer could be both misleading and good. I'd happily vote your answer up if you edit it into a good answer. And please note that there's nothing personal here -- it's your answer that's not good, not you yourself, and I've only been trying to explain why because you asked.